# Duplicate Page Redirect: How do I find the connection?

Tags: facebook, duplicates, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I am developing a Facebook application where I want to filter a user's friends by school.  The problem I am having is when there are duplicate pages for a school user's may not have the same page ID.

Ex) http://www.facebook.com/pages/UT-Austin/106258719412206 will redirect to http://www.facebook.com/UTAustinTX?rf=106258719412206

I have not been able to find any information on how to find these redirect connections.  Ideally I would like:

1. If I am trying to view a page that is to be redirected as in the above example; What is the page ID I am being redirected to?
2. If I have a page ID; What are all of the duplicate page IDs related?

Comment: It does not look like these are available via the API.

Comment: I was hoping someone had found a way to determine which IDs are related to each other.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is graph search the name and ideally the location.  In your example, just graph searching the name provided the new page as the first result.
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=UT+Austin&type=place&access_token=YOURTOKEN

It's not ideal, but I think it's the only way to deal with this.

A few things to note:
You can compare domains in your situation.
Your [first node](https://graph.facebook.com/106258719412206):

```
{
category: "University",
description: "The University of Texas at Austin is a public research-intensive university located in Austin, Texas, United States. It is the flagship institution of the University of Texas System. Founded in 1883, its campus is approximately 0.25 miles from the Texas State Capitol in Austin. The institution has the fifth-largest single-campus enrollment in the nation, with over 50,000 undergraduate and graduate students and over 24,000 faculty and staff.The University of Texas at Austin was named one of the original eight Public Ivy institutions and was inducted into the American Association of Universities in 1929. The university is a major center for academic research, with research expenditures exceeding $640 million for the 2009–2010 school year. The university houses seven museums and seventeen libraries, including the Lyndon Baines Johnson Library and Museum and the Blanton Museum of Art, and operates various auxiliary research facilities, such as the J. J. Pickle Research Campus and the McDonald Observatory. Among university faculty are recipients of the Nobel Prize, Pulitzer Prize, the Wolf Prize, and the National Medal of Science, as well as many other awards.",
is_community_page: true,
is_published: true,
talking_about_count: 8,
website: "http://www.utexas.edu",
were_here_count: 0,
id: "106258719412206",
name: "UT Austin",
link: "http://www.facebook.com/pages/UT-Austin/106258719412206",
likes: 5143
}
```

has www.utexas.edu

Your [second node](https://graph.facebook.com/UTAustinTX) has the same.

You can probably use the `is_community_page: true` as a trigger that you should look for some equivalent ID via graph search.  That's not true in all situations but because you're dealing with universities, I would imagine every single one (at least in the USA) has a claimed FB page in which case `is_community_page` would be false or the attribute would not exist (nil).

Also depending on your business you could MTurk this task or probably even use a scraper.  I don't thing those are great solutions to solve this at scale but I'm suggesting because if you're only dealing with universities, you could probably afford the Mturk or the heavy lifting of a scrape.

I did confirm you could use a scraper to look for the redirecting javascript and parse out the new ID on the original page.

I know this kinda sucks but hopefully it helps